# Override Create and CreateMany From Trait with Relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a migration to transfer data from an old software into a new custom web application.  There are a large number of data fields in the old software that will not be actively used in the new software.  However, they may be useful at some point, so I wish to transfer them to my new software and store in a separate "archives" table that can be searched.  To do this, I have created an "Archive" model, and a trait "ArchiveTrait". The idea is to extract the attributes on create that come with an "_archive" prefix, and store the key/value/type in another table.  The data is currently in JSON and is structured as a tree, for (extremely simplified) example:

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "first_name": "Bob",
  "last_name": "Johnson",
  "_archive_previous_account_holder": "Randy Johnson",
  "locations": [
    {
      "street": "123 Main Street",
      "city": "Bloomington",
      "_archive_house_color": "red"
      "appliances": [
        {
          "make": "GE",
          "model": "GSS25G"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I have written the following trait, it is used on the Account, Location and Appliance models:

```
trait ArchiveTrait {

    public static function create(array $attributes = []) {
        $archives = [];
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value ) {
            if (preg_match('/^_archive/', $key) ) {
                if( ! is_null($value) and $value != "" ) {
                    $archives[$key] = $value;
                }
                unset( $attributes[$key] );
            }
        }
        $model = static::query()->create($attributes);
        foreach ($archives as $key => $value ) {
            $model->archives()->create([
                'key' => $key,
                'value' => $value,
                'cast' => gettype($value)
            ]);
        }
        return $model;
    }

    public static function createMany(iterable $records) {
        return new Collection(
            array_map(function ($attributes) {
                $archives = [];
                foreach ($attributes as $key => $value ) {
                    if (preg_match('/^_archive/', $key) ) {
                        if( ! is_null($value) and $value != "" ) {
                            $archives[$key] = $value;
                        }
                        unset( $attributes[$key] );
                    }
                }
                $model = static::query()->create($attributes);
                foreach ($archives as $key => $value ) {
                    $model->archives()->create([
                        'key' => $key,
                        'value' => $value,
                        'cast' => gettype($value)
                    ]);
                }
            }, $records)
        );
    }

    public function archives() {
        return $this->morphMany(Archive::class, 'archivable');
    }
}
```

It works awesome, except that the extended "create" and "createMany" functions are not called on for Location and Appliance if I do something like:

```
$a = Account::create($account);
$l = $a->locations()->create($location)
$x = $l->appliances()->create($appliance)
```

I assume this is because am calling on the relationship rather than the static model? Is there any way I can access the modified "create" and "createMany" through the relationship? Or, would I be better off doing extending these methods in a parent "ArchivedModel" class that I could extend with Account, Location and Appliance?  I also do realize that I can simply call everything statically from the Model itself, e.g.:

```
Account::create($account);
Location::create($account['location'])
etc.
```

But at this point I just want the elegant solution above to work, because it will be easier to pick and choose which models I apply it to.

FYI, I currently have about 5k such accounts, that are each about 4 levels deep, and each level has between 2 and 20 "_archive" fields. Also I already have a sizable JSON file that was exported and provided to me in this format, and would prefer to not change the data structure, if possible.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're looking for something to happen when a model is created, deleted, etc. you want to look at [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events)